# Версия или вариант партитуры

Tags: семантика

Допустим, имеется партитура какого-либо произведения для оркестра, и есть другая, этого же произведения, партитура, но с некоторыми редакционными изменениями. Предполагается, что обе они равнозначны (в художественном смысле нет перевеса одной над другой). Какое обозначение в данном случае лучше подойдёт для каждой редакции: вариант партитуры или версия партитуры? Есть ли существенная разница в употреблении этих понятий?

Answer (score 1):

Версия- это явно выраженное индивидуальное авторское видение и представление чего-либо, скорее динамического(а не статического), как: спектакль,  мотив убийства, предполагаемого хода событий, исполнения музыкального или поэтического произведения и т.д. здесь необходим суд зрителя (слушателя) на принятие-неприятие.
Вариант- это как бы копия с уже принятым некоторыми небольшими отклонения от уже первоначального источника. Как бы копия с допуском. Мы же говорим: "второй ВАРИАНТ контрольной работы для экзаменам", но не " вторая ВЕРСИЯ контрольной работы", если речь идёт об уже официальном принятом ВТОРОМ ВИДЕ контрольной. Это данное.. Другое дело, если ученик написал своё новое, нетрадиционной решение(исполнение) задачи, которую учителю надо ещё продумать и оценить как что-то новое, необычное. В таком случае я бы скорее сказала "новая, другая, авторская ВЕРСИЯ" решения задачи.
Вообще надо сказать, что слово "Вариант"  " лезет  во все дыры" и подменяет собой все тонкости русского языка так, что перестаёшь чувствовать выразительные  прелести русского языка

Answer (score 0):

В другой версии должны быть текстовые отличия — другие ноты.
Похожий пример: *режиссёрская версия фильма*.

"Вариант партитуры" — в общем смысле подходит, но здесь нет точности (в чём именно разница).

В таком случае говорят так: *другая редакция произведения*.

Comment: А если разница в динамике (нюансах), слово "вариант" не подойдёт? Как подробности повлияют на употребление?

Comment: Нюансы часто пишут не композиторы, а издательства. А версия — это другой вариант от самого автора.

Comment: Вообще вопрос заключался в различиях между понятиями "версия" и "вариант"

Comment: Различие в том, что версии произведения искусства принадлежат одному автору, а вариант — это про любую разницу.